# Are there any manufacturers of color image sensors who publish their datasheets?

Tags: datasheet, image-sensor

I need a 1/2.7" image sensor with MIPI interface for a project. After some research I thought OV2710-1E might be a good choice, so I tried to find a datasheet, and found nothing. So I requested their sales if I can buy these sensors, sign the NDA and receive the datasheets. Their response was that first I need to buy at least 10000 sensors (which I obviously can't afford), so I am now wondering if any of image sensor manufacturers are more open about their products?

Comment: I doubt it......

Comment: Consider using a sensor module with a lens mount, these can be used with a microscope. Or some lens-less camera module. A MIPI interface might not be possible then.

Comment: What happens if you put "ov2710" into google? Full datasheet of OV2710-1E was third link for me.

Comment: Call back Don't mention your previous call. Ask for pricing on quantities 100k, 200k, 300k. Ask for samples to evaluate.

Comment: @Justme Thank you! Only found 2-page product brief, but this looks like a full datasheet distributed under NDA leaked